# How to programmatically escape quotes andd slashes

Tags: python, escaping

I need a python script to call a bash script on windows.
So basically I must make a subprocess call form python, that will call cygwin with the -c option that will call the script I need,
The problem is that this script takes a few arguments and that these arguments are full os spaces and quotes and slashes.
I'm using code like the following

```
arq_saida_unix = arq_saida.replace("\\","/")
subprocess.call("C:\\cygwin64\\bin\\bash \".\\retirarVirgula.sh\\ \""+arq_saida+"\"")
```

Or I'm directly escaping, which sometimes takes me to as much as 8 backslashes in a row, for a backslash to get to my script must be escaped i) in bash ii) in cmd.exe iii) in python

all of this is error prone and takes quite some time every time to get it right.

Is there a better way of doing it? Ideally I wouldn't have any escaping backslashes, but anything that avoids the triple-slash double quote above would be nice.

I tried to use re.escape, but could figure out how exactly to use it , except as a replacement to .replace("\","/") and similar.

Answer (score 2):

Don't pass a single string to `call`; instead, pass a list consisting of the command name and one argument per element. This saves you from needing to protect special characters from shell interpretation.

```
subprocess.call(["retirarVirgula.sh", arq_saida], executable=r"C:\cygwin64\bin\bash")
```

Note: I'm assuming `arq_saida` contains the single argument to pass to the script; if the script takes multiple arguments, then `arc_saida` should probably be built as a list as well:

```
arq_saida = ["arg", "arg two", "arg three"]
subprocess.call(["retirarVirgula.sh"] + arq_saida, executable=r"C:\cygwin64\bin\bash")
```

Comment: I've usually seen `subprocess.call` with the executable as the first element in the list, not as a seperate `executable` keyword argument - is there any difference?

Comment: In this case, not much. I prefer using it to move `bash` out of the way, so you can focus on the fact that you are running a script with its arguments, rather than passing the script and its arguments all as arguments to `bash`.

Comment: That sounds reasonable. However, it seems that on my machine, doing `subprocess.call(["foo.sh"], executable="/bin/bash")` starts Bash (probably with a argv[0] of foo.sh), but not foo.sh itself.

Comment: Thanks for commenting on using a list as argument, but I'm afraid the problem is far from solved. My code was just a non-working example. Actually On must use the -c argument and so must put quotes binding retirarVirgula.sh and arg together, so that everything is passed to bash, the args themselves need to be escaped because they contain strings, and it is hard to know how many times.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood how `executable` works. You should be able to use `['bash', 'retirarVirgula.sh', 'arg1', 'arg2']` instead of using `-c`, though.

Comment: Are you quite sure I don't need the -c?I do admit I don't fully understand how bash is supposed to work in non interactive mode. If I try in cmd.exe D:\Boulot\Cygwin\bin\bash.exe echo hello > "D:\ff" I get /usr/bin/bash: echo: No such file or directory but if I try D:\Boulot\Cygwin\bin\bash.exe -c echo hello > "D:\ff" the ff file is nicely created. I suppose when you call from python the same applies?